# How to set timeoffset for a specific date with JDdate

Tags: joomla-3.4, date, jdate

I tried to apply timezone offset to a variable. Here is my code

```
$time_offset = "Australia/Sydney";
$start_time = "2015-07-31 15:03:00";

$date_end = JDate::getInstance('now', $time_offset);
$date_start = JDate::getInstance($start_time, $time_offset);

echo $date_end;
echo $date_start;
```

*$date_end* is returned a correct value but *$date_start* returned the original value (didn't change).

Is there anything I missed here?
Thanks

Comment: JDate extends [**PHP's DateTime class**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and this behavior is inherited from the parent class and not from JDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating JDate object

```
$time_offset = "Australia/Sydney";
$start_time = "2015-07-31 15:03:00";

$date_end = JDate::getInstance('now', $time_offset);
$date_start = new JDate($start_time);
$date_start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($time_offset));

echo $date_end;
echo $date_start;
```

Comment: It's kinda tricky the way the DateTime class handles this - Setting the Timezone on a new date object, but at the end it does make sense.